# Can I parallelize a SQL query in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, postgresql

I have an Excel workbook that connects to a PostgreS db via ODBC.
Using VBA it executes 27 SQL queries one by one and copies each resulting set to
a different worksheet.

I am content with the data I get, but the performance is mediocre. The database should have plenty of resources.

Can I parallelize/multi-thread the SQL queries? I have read that parallelization  is not possible in VBA, per se.

Comment: You can append all the sql together `SELECT * FROM foo;SELECT * FROM bar;` and submit it all at once. Then you can move through all of the recordsets returned with [NextRecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I did'nt know this. I will try it at the workplace on thursday and report back.on the performance gained.

Comment: @JNevill : excellent.

Comment: You could also toss all of your select statements into a stored procedure and have it return all the recordsets. Then you just call your proc once and cycle through the results with the `NextRecordset` feature. I've never tested that with Postgres, but it should work, theoretically.

Comment: Are your queries all from the same table?

Comment: No. they querry different Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @JNevills advice I concatenated the 27 queries in one mega-query
separated by " ; " with a total weight of 54.778 characters.

Execution time:

- 27 queries sequentially: 45 seconds
- 1 mega-query: 30 seconds

I learned, that I work on a well seasoned db-version - namely PostgreS 
9.3.11.

Even if I had more cores this version coudn't be bothered to use them.
If I execute the mega-query in Squirrel it takes about 20 seconds.

The performance might be better with an up-to-date database.

Sketch of the solution

```vb
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn

for i = 1 to 27
   call writeRecordSetToSheet(rs, sheetname)
   Set rs = rs.NextRecordset  '<- magic line for accessing the other 26 recordsets
next i
```